# Can I send sms using Sinch with Squarespace, which does not give access to server side code

Tags: javascript, squarespace, sinch

I need to send SMS using Sinch from a Squarespace app, which does not provide access to server side code. I am wondering if their JavaScript SDK can do it, but I can't seem to figure out any help of this. Has anyone does this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but you should not do that because you secret will be exposed so any one could use your account. The code that sends sms should be on server side (in any  language you want)

Comment: Thanks cjensen, I consider to send request to an intermediate server, which will further send request to Sinch.